# CancellationToken is even null

Tags: c#, task

In my application I run a `Task` which execute an heavy operation, I'm trying to stop the execution of that `Task`. Actually I declared in my class the following structure:

```
public class Foo
{
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private CancellationToken token;

    public void Start()
    {
        var task = new Task(async () => {
           try
           {
               await new Bot().StartAsync(token);
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
           }
        }, token));

        task.Start();
    }
}
```

as you can see I have declared a `CancellationTokenSource` which allow me to stop the task execution when the user click on a button:

```
StopTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Now, inside the `StartAsync` method I have the following code:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    ApplicationToken = token;

    while(true)
    {
       if(ApplicationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

The `ApplicationToken` store the token passed as parameter in the class of `StartAsync` method.

After the button click event, the request should be cancelled but nothing happen.

Then I check for each iteration if a cancellation request was made, but the variable value is even `false`.

Comment: You may want to clarify the title of your question. As `CancellationToken` is a `struct`, it cannot be `null`.

Comment: I guess you're passing different token. Why not to create `Cancel` method inside `Foo` class. So to cancel the task just call `foo.Cancel();` BTW i can't see relation between `StartAsync`'s implementation and `Foo` class here.

Comment: @Luthfay the `StartAsync` method is part of another class, the `Foo` class only declare a `Task` which contains the heavy operation

Comment: O sorry, didn't see that..

Comment: What does "heavy operation" mean? Regardless of how much stuff is going on in that `while` loop, then it certainly won't check for cancellation until the loop cycles.

Comment: @KennethK. in my case the loop execute a internet download each 1 minute and elaborate some data, so adding a break point I can see the checking on `IsCancellationRequested`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that you forgot to `token = tokenSource.Token;`

Edit1: You should check for cancellation using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`

Edit2:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CancellationTokenPOC
{
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        TokenPOC t = new TokenPOC();
        var longRunningTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                t.token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                await Task.Delay(10000);
            }

        });
        Console.ReadKey();
        t.source.Cancel();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("finishing");
    }
}

class TokenPOC
{
    public CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public CancellationToken token;
    public TokenPOC()
    {
        token = source.Token;
    }
}
}
```

This token gets cancelled and ends the program as expected...

Comment: I implemented the @sean logic and still same problem

Comment: this won't work, I suspect because the method that you propose need to be used on the main thread, I need to stop the execution of a task

Comment: @JuveMerda try my code, its a simple console app... i think theres something wrong with the code you're not showing...

Comment: Okay I understood why this doesn't work for me. Essentially I'm trying to stop a Task that run inside the Task of `Foo` class. The Task that I'm trying to stop is part of `Bot` class, so the cancellation token need to propagade the value in that Task, not in the main thread

Comment: pls don't forget to mark as answer if this solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a different token than the one you are trying to cancel. You can eliminate

```
private CancellationToken token;
```

and instead pass in to `StartAsync()`

```
tokenSource.Token
```

Comment: @JuveMerda You need to start the task with `Start()` or use `Task.Run()`.

Comment: the task is started, I just doesn't write the code in the question, I'll update

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the below:

```
public class Foo
{
   var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token();

   public void Start() {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
               await new Bot().StartAsync(token);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }, token).ContinueWith(task =>
          {
              if (!task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted)
              {
                 // Log
              }
          }, token);
    }

    StopTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
          cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `StartAsync` lacks await operators and it will run synchronously.

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    ApplicationToken = token;

    while (true)
    { 
        if (ApplicationToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        await Task.Delay(10, ApplicationToken); // => you may change it to concrete task
    }
}
```

Secondly, the `CancellationToken` at `Foo` class is redundant, you don't even initialize it.

`new Bot().StartAsync(tokenSource.Token);` inside Start method is not awaited so execution on the current method continues before the call is completed.

And since `Start` method is void you should use `GetAwaiter()` method in order to execute task at `Bot` class.

```
public void Start()
{
    try
    {
        new Bot().StartAsync(tokenSource.Token).GetAwaiter();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Finally, if `StopTask_Click` method is member of `Foo` class, then it should works fine.

---

This is an example how to cancel the task using `CancellationTokenSource`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Foo foo = new Foo();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foo.Start();          
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foo.Cancel();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            new Bot().StartAsync(tokenSource.Token).GetAwaiter();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}

public class Bot
{
    private CancellationToken ApplicationToken;

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        ApplicationToken = token;

        while (true)
        { 
            if (ApplicationToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;
            await Task.Delay(10, ApplicationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still remain but I noticed this: the token inside the Foo class have the IsCancellationRequested setted to true after the button click, instead the token passed as parameter in the StartAsync function is still false. So the seems the code doesn't reflect the change? –

Comment: You don't need to set `IsCancellationRequested` to true. Just call `tokenSource.Cancel();` Could you point me out where's StopTask_Click located? Is it member of Foo class? or?

Comment: yep is part of `Foo` class, only `StartAsync` is part of the `Bot` class

Comment: I have reproduced your issue in my environment and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Okay I understood why this doesn't work for me. Essentially I'm trying to stop a Task that run inside the Task of Foo class. The Task that I'm trying to stop is part of Bot class, so the cancellation token need to propagade the value in that Task, not in the main thread

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182810/discussion-between-juvemerda-and-luthfay).